# How to access specific data that is linked to the user after he/she logs in

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a created a database with 6 tables and have them 15 times under a different schema. Each schema representing a campus/school.

The task i need to complete is to create a login and after the user/teacher logged in, it should only display the students and information linked to the user/teacher.

I can create a basic UWP app login that compares the username and password from the SQL database.

I just need guidelines on how i will need to approach this to retrieve only the the logged on users information.

The output i am expecting is that when user_1 logs in, only the information linked to that user gets displayed.

Comment: Repeating the same tables just to separate content (in this case this seems to be kind of *multi-client* issue) is - in almost any case - the wrong approach. You should rather use something like a `ClientID` and compound keys. You can use iTVFs to return a resultset filtered for a given ClientID. In your approach it might even be better to have a dedicated database per client... It might help to explain a bit more about your goals... Is this training / homework exercise? Please give some more background...

Comment: This is for a practical assignment. The first assignment was to create the database, and for the second assignment we need to create the app.

Comment: Well, I asked for more background... Is there any need, which forces you into this approach, or did you just think, that *one schema per Client* might be a good concept? In other words: Is a different approach acceptable?

Comment: This was the requirements from my first assignment to create a schema for each campus/school.

Comment: Did the requirements really force you into structurally identical table with different schemas? This sounds rather weird... Why not create a master database and clone that for each client? Your problem seems to be, that each `SELECT * FROM xyz.SomeTable` should know *magically* which client bound schema should replace "xyz". Correct? You can define a different default schema for each login, but this is the road to hell... You might create all statements dynamically. This is the road to hell too. You might use VIEWS or iTVFs with lots of `UNION ALL` and a `WHERE`. Again a road to hell...

Comment: Yes the assignment specified that we should create the different tables under the schemas.

Answer (score 0):

You get the idea that this approach can be problematic, but let's run with it anyways. In a database every object belongs to a schema - correct? Often you write queries like

```
select col1 ... from orders order by ...;
```

Now what table is actually used to satisfy that query? You probably learned about the dbo schema because it exists in every database. If you reference a table by name only, the database engine must find the actual table to be used.  It will first look in the current [user's default schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to see if that table exists. If it does, then that table is used. If not, the engine will then [look in the dbo schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/ownership-and-user-schema-separation-in-sql-server) for that table.

Knowing that, you can write your queries to take advantage of that logic. Note "can" - this is not a recommendation but it will fulfill your goal. If you write your queries using one part names, all those names will be relative to the default schema of the current user at execution time.

So assume user X is has a default schema of Z. Your app attempts to execute the query "select * from orders order by orderDate desc;". The table Z.orders will be used as the source if present. If that table does not exist in schema Z, the engine will use dbo.Orders. And if that table does not exists, an error will be generated.

So does that work with whatever framework you are using in your app? Don't know. Note also that you are writing an application. All of this you can do in your own written code. And if you can dynamically add a schema name to your queries, you can also do all sorts of things to "customize" the results for any reason. Quite simply - it's just all code so do whatever you want.